# How to export specific DDPs from a set of DDPs?

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I have a set of data driven pages and I would like to have a string parameter in the tool that allows me to export specific pages from the set of data driven pages. An example would be if I had a set of 50 pages, I could just enter "1-10, 20, 35-40" and it would export only those pages.

```
import arcpy

inputList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
bckGrndLyrs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
pageRng = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
outputLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
exportDPI = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for lyrs in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrs.name in inputList:
        lyrs.visible = False
    elif lyrs.name in bckGrndLyrs:
        lyrs.visible = True  
    else:
        lyrs.visible = False

for inFC in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(inputList, "", df):
    if inFC.name in inputList:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Activating " + inFC.name + " Layer")
        inFC.visible = True

        for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
          if str(pageNum) in pageRng:
              mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
              blockName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Block
              for titleItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
                  if titleItem.name == 'EditedTitle':
                    arcpy.AddMessage("...Changing title to " + inFC.name)
                    titleItem.text = inFC.name + str(pageNum)
              arcpy.AddMessage("......Refreshing Dataframe")
              arcpy.RefreshTOC()
              arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
              arcpy.AddMessage(".........Exporting " + inFC.name + " " + blockName + " as PDF")
              arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outputLocation + "/" + inFC.name + " " + blockName + ".pdf", resolution=exportDPI)
        inFC.visible = False

del mxd
```

Comment: Convert your `pageRng` to a list first, and then check for the page number in that list.  See [How to convert numeric string ranges to a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405208/how-to-convert-numeric-string-ranges-to-a-list-in-python)